# Are there limitations of data in a Javascript, table, or frame?

Tags: javascript, frame

I am maintaining a page that displays a table inside of a div inside of a frame.

It works great but recently the amount of data has increased and it is not all displaying.  To build the table data, it is a jQuery `.get`.  There are about 2000 rows of data to the table.  Only about 1000 rows display.  There are six columns.  It is all text.

I have searched for data limitations, studied the source, debugged, but still not able to determine why the data is being truncated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where does the data come from?

Comment: From a view in a Notes database.  The url is  urlstr2 =  '/'+ mydbpath + '/myview?openview&count=-1&restricttocategory='    etc   and I call the url with this statement:  $.get(urlstr2, function(data){

Comment: It could be that the database is limiting how many rows of data it will show at once.

Comment: Thank you.  It wasn't the database, but there was a setting in the Notes server that was set to display 1000 rows max.  Good to know!